# Using Javascript or jQuery if else statements to use different variables when JSON Payload has different format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a school project where I have to create an "if else" statement to use different variables when the JSON format is different.

Below is the payload that I want to extract and use as handlebars:

```
"templateName": "xyzTemplate",
        "payload": {
            "categories": "chocolates",
            "modifier": "chocolate-detail",
            "header": "Your Chocolates",
            "channelType": "W",
            "accounts": [{
                "subTitle": "Sorry, I am having trouble processing your current request.",
                "acctId": "I love chocolates",

                    "type": "Dark Chocolates",
                    "extraParams": {
                        "amountOfChocolates": "4386249702964395",
                        "chocolatesEaten": "27000"
```

However, sometimes the payload becomes like this:

```
"templateName": "xyzTemplate",
    "payload": {
      "categories": "chocolates",
      "modifier": "chocolate-detail",
      "header": "Your Chocolates",
      "channelType": "W",
      "accounts": [
        {
          "subTitle": "Sorry, I am having trouble processing your current request.",
          "acctId": "I love chocolates",
          "account": {
            "type": "Dark Chocolates",
            "extraParams": {
              "amountOfChocolates": "4386249702964395",
                        "chocolatesEaten": "27000"
            },
```

I would like to use the following variable, var data, to reflect different payloads. Example:

```
    var alldata = [];
    //if payload has accounts[0].account
    var data = var data = resp.payload.accounts[0].account;
    //else
    var data = resp.payload.accounts[0];
```

Would really appreciate your help with this one.

Comment: What are the changes between both JSON?

Comment: Looks like the same json structure to me

Comment: Sorry, I thought I removed the word 'account' from the first payload. I wanted to edit the question, but I don't see any button to allow me to edit

Comment: @stoltenheim [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53393367/edit)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly: 
use 'sub' account prop if available, otherwise use account?

```
const account = resp.payload.accounts[0];
const data = account.account || account;
```

Note: prefer usage of 'const' and 'let' instead of 'var'. (But you might see that later on in your programming class :D)

Comment: I downvoted because you're answering to something that is unclear. There is no difference between both JSON

Comment: True, the json is identical and unclear. The comments in his code example indicate a general notion of what he wants? Seems more like a copy/paste error with the json

Comment: sorry, I remembered removing the word 'account from the first JSON code. Not sure why it's still there and I can't edit because I can't find the edit button

Comment: Anyways, I tried your method and it works! Thanks a million! There's so much to learn.